# (opencv) imread with CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE yields a 4 channels Mat

Tags: opencv, image-processing

The following code reads an image from a file into a `cv::Mat` object.

```
#include <string>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

cv::Mat load_image(std::string img_path)
{
  cv::Mat img = cv::imread(img_path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
  cv::Scalar intensity = img.at<uchar>(0, 0);
  std::cout << intensity << std::endl;
  return img;
}
```

I would expect the `cv::Mat` to have only one channel (namely, the intensity of the image) but it has 4.

```
$ ./test_load_image
[164, 0, 0, 0]
```

I also tried converting the image with

```
cv::Mat gray(img.size(), CV_8UC1);
img.convertTo(gray, CV_8UC1);
```

but the `gray` matrix is also a 4 channels one.

I'd like to know if it's possible to have a single channel `cv::Mat`. Intuitively, that's what I would expect to have when dealing with a grayscale (thus, single channel) image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The matrix is single channel. You're just reading the values in the wrong way.

`Scalar` is a struct with 4 values. Constructing a `Scalar` with a single value will result in a `Scalar` with the first value set, and the remaining at zero.

In your case, only the first values make sense. The zeros are as default for `Scalar`.

However, you don't need to use a `Scalar`:

```
uchar intensity = img.at<uchar>(0, 0);
std::cout << int(intensity) << std::endl; // Print the value, not the ASCII character
```